# Create Hashset with a large number of elements (1M)

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have to create a HashSet with the elements from 1 to N+1, where N is a large number (1M).

For example, if N = 5, the HashSet will have then integers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.

The only way I have found is:

```
HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>(N);

for (int i = 1; i <= (N + 1) ; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(i);
}
```

Are there another faster (more efficient) ways to do it?

Comment: Faster? Unlikely. Shorter? Sure: `new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 6))`.

Comment: You say that you want to populate the list with values from 1 to N+1 but your code populates it with values from 0 to N.

Comment: Nearing 1200 questions and still not knowing how to ask one. Please read [ask], give us some more context and show what you have tried.

Comment: What's the problem behind the question? `6` is a tiny number and `Add` is fast enough. Is the real number of items 1000 or 10K perhaps?

Comment: @canton7, it didn't originally. That edit was made about the same time as I posted my comment, probably as a direct consequence of my comment. It would be nice if the OP could mention that they edited the question in a comment of their own, so comments like mine don't look insane.

Comment: Yes, it is around 1 million but, for an example, I'm not going to write down from 1 to 1000001. It's obvious. IT IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE.

Comment: @VansFannel it's not obvious the way it's written. The delay is caused by reallocations, not `Add`

Comment: Providing an example is all well and good but you still need to provide ALL the relevant information. If the actual number of values will be very large then say so. Also, what's wrong with writing "{1, 2, 3, ..., 1000001}"?

Comment: @VansFannel on the contrary, it's obvious to *me*, which is why I posted the answer you want, because I've had to do the same in the past *and* answered a lot of similar questions. Imagine having to process eg 1M air tickets and *improving* performance by 100 or more simply by reducing allocations

Comment: @VansFannel and yet, you accepted an answer that's as slow as the question's code

Comment: @VansFannel I didn't downvote. On the contrary, I tried to guess what the real question was and explain how to actually solve this. I also explain the *only* case where using the constructor can lead in faster execution. Isn't *that* what you wanted?

Comment: @VansFannel: i tend to downvote as well now, because you have edited your question to use the constructor that initializes the capacity, which makes the answer of Panagiotis look redundant- Btw, you should use the correct capacity which is not N but N+1.

Comment: *"...faster (more efficient)..."* -- Efficiency is not a synonym for speed. An algorithm is more efficient when it uses fewer resources, like RAM or CPU or network bandwidth. An efficient algorithm can be slower than a less efficient algorithm. So please clarify if you are interested for optimizing for speed or for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on [@Enigmativity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73797681/1086121), here's a proper benchmark using BenchmarkDotNet:

```
public class Benchmark
{
    private const int N = 1000000;

    [Benchmark]
    public HashSet<int> EnumerableRange() => new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, N + 1));

    [Benchmark]
    public HashSet<int> NoPreallocation()
    {
        var result = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int n = 1; n < N + 1; n++)
        {
            result.Add(n);
        }
        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public HashSet<int> Preallocation()
    {
        var result = new HashSet<int>(N);
        for (int n = 1; n < N + 1; n++)
        {
            result.Add(n);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program).Assembly);
    }
}
```

With the results:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EnumerableRange | 29.17 ms | 0.743 ms | 2.179 ms |
| NoPreallocation | 23.96 ms | 0.471 ms | 0.775 ms |
| Preallocation | 11.68 ms | 0.233 ms | 0.665 ms |

As we can see, using linq is a bit slower than not using linq (as expected), and pre-allocating saves a significant amount of time.

Comment: (Please don't accept this: Panagiotis Kanavos's answer is probably the best, as it directly addresses the underlying problem. Enigmativity's adds some numbers, and mine refines them)

Answer (score 5):

6 is a tiny number of items so I suspect the *real* problem is adding a few thousand items. The delays in this case are caused by buffer reallocations, not the speed of `Add` itself.

The solution to this is to specify even an approximate capacity when constructing the HashSet :

```
var set=new HashSet<int>(1000);
```

If, and only if, the input implements `ICollection<T>`, [the `HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs#L92) will check the size of input collection and use it as its capacity:

```
if (collection is ICollection<T> coll)
{
    int count = coll.Count;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        Initialize(count);
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

Most containers in .NET use buffers internally to store data. This is *far* faster than implementing containers using pointers, nodes etc due to CPU cache and RAM access delays. Accessing the next item in the CPU's cache is far faster than chasing a pointer in RAM in all CPUs.

The downside is that each time the buffer is full a new one will have to be allocated. Typically, this buffer will have twice the size of the original buffer. Adding items one by one can result in log2(N) reallocations. This works fine for a moderate number of items but can result in a lot of orphaned buffers when adding eg 1000 items one by one. All those temporary buffers will have to be garbage collected at some point, causing additional delays.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code to test the three options:

```
var N = 1000000;
var trials = new List<(int method, TimeSpan duration)>();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    HashSet<int> numbers1 = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, N + 1));
    sw.Stop();
    trials.Add((1, sw.Elapsed));
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    HashSet<int> numbers2 = new HashSet<int>(N);
    for (int n = 1; n < N + 1; n++)
        numbers2.Add(n);
    sw.Stop();
    trials.Add((2, sw.Elapsed));
    HashSet<int> numbers3 = new HashSet<int>(N);
    foreach (int n in Enumerable.Range(1, N + 1))
        numbers3.Add(n);
    sw.Stop();
    trials.Add((3, sw.Elapsed));
}

for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    Console.WriteLine(trials.Where(x => x.method == j).Average(x => x.duration.TotalMilliseconds));
```

Typical output is this:

```
31.314788
16.493208
16.493208
```

It is nearly twice as fast to preallocate the capacity of the `HashSet<int>`.

There is no difference between the traditional loop and a LINQ `foreach` option.

Comment: Use BenchmarkDotNet for benchmarking

Comment: @canton7 - Fair enough. Or I could roll my own and run the code several times to get it warmed up. I didn't just go with the first execution. ;-)

Comment: There are a significant number of factors to take into consideration when micro-benchmarking -- it's not just as simple as "get it warmed up". BenchmarkDotNet takes care of all of that for you, which is why the compiler and runtime teams use it for their benchmarking

Comment: @canton7 - In your opinion, did I get a meaningful result?

Comment: I think the general conclusion of "pre-allocating is a lot quicker" is undoubtedly right. I'd be nervous about asserting "nearly twice as fast" without a proper benchmark